# How many troops do you have to donate to get xp?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I was donating Wizards to my clan and I didn't receive any xp for some donations(I didn't see the (blue) message with ...xp received.
Normally I donate 5 Archers and I always get 5 XP.

Do I have to donate a certain amount of troops to get the xp?

Comment: Did you donate through the Clan War map, or did you donate in response to an incoming request?

Comment: I donated trough the incoming requests.

Comment: Interesting. Donating troops through a request should **always** give xp. Though I haven't played in 2 weeks, so I can't verify for certain.

Comment: The game is a bit slow sometimes. Happened before, and it also happened that donated troops never made it to the receiver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did get the XP, the message didn't popped under the request button.

You always get XP from donating troops, the message only shows when you donate 5 troops or the request is filled up.

Answer (score 0):

The exp will be rewarded when you have donated 5 troops or when the request is filled up.

Answer (score 0):

I have always gotten experience when I donate. You just might have not seen what it says before it goes away.